# Silverstripe add UploadField to ModelAdmin failed

Tags: php, silverstripe, modeladmin

I am trying to add an UploadField to ModelAdmin by creating an extension, after the GridFieldList. But I always get an error " Call to a member function FormAction() on a non-object in ..../framework/forms/FormField.php on line 161". I can add TextField,DropdownField without any problems, but no luck with UploadField.
Did I miss something?

```
<code>
    class MyExtension extends Extension{
        public static $has_one = array(
            'ImportCSV' => 'File'
        );
        public function updateEditForm($form){
            $fields = $form->Fields();
            $fields->push(
                new TextField('Title', 'Title')
            );//This one works
            $fields->push(
                new UploadField('ImportCSV', 'Import CSV')
            );//This one not working
        }
    }
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing an `Extension` (Specifically a `DataExtension`) then you'd use `updateCMSFields($fields)` which is passed an instance of `FieldList` by reference.

But to add the `UploadField` as I think you want, either add it to a `DataExtension` that extends (decorates) `File` in a call to `updateCMSFields()` or change `extends Extension` to `extends DataExtension` in your example above, and run `dev/build flush=all`

Comment: Thx, @theruss. I am confused with Extension. Actually, I am trying to add one UploadField and one Button on the ModelAdmin page. When the user upload a CSV and click the button, it will modify some records in DB. So in this case, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do yes. Try and use what's already there and modify it: Copy `ReportAdmin` and rename it. Strip out everything apart from `getEditForm()`, then modify _that_ with your custom fields and logic. 

Even better would be to modify `ModelAdmin`'s built in upload CSV form (See the `CsvBulkLoader` class) and modify that to your needs. There are several good tutorials on silverstripe.org that cover this sort of thing. But as always, you need to think outside the box a bit to adapt what are essentially other people's ideas, and fit them into what you're trying to do.